# Facebook cant pass $_GET var from tab app url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Ive currently setup a Facebook tab on my Facebook fanpage.

It seems im not able to get any vars defined in my tab app url like:

www.facebook.com/pages/myApp/177845772355947?sk=app_379422318804869&share=var_i_want_to_pass_via_GET_to_PHP

So in my PHP im simply trying to do a

```
echo $_GET["share"];
```

However it seems I cant pass on anything from the tab app url.

I did the same thing with my canvas page url like:
http://apps.facebook.com/myCanvasApp/?share=var_i_want_to_pass_via_GET_to_PHP

And here I can easily echo it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/, last paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `app_data` field in the `signed_request`.

Here's two pages on Facebook's Developer site that cover what you want.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/#integrating